# How do I reset Visual Studio 2013 completely

Tags: asp.net, reset

Okay so I'm trying to create a new website, and the first time I created the site I accidentally saved it to the wrong folder. Well instead of just copying the folder to the correct location and having to deal with that headache I decided to just delete the old folder and make a new site in the correct place. Now it keeps giving me numbers at the the end though. I named the site PNI (and I like that name and want to keep it) so when I made it the second time it named it PNI(2) I tried deleting that and resetting then environment, removing the old site names from the "recent" list, but it named the site PNI(3). How can I reset VB so that it will stop counting my sites?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 places you might need to check to clear out old sites

1. In VS, go to menu `Tools > Options` and then click the `Projects and Solutions` node and look at the path in `Projects location`. Go to that path and delete any folders you see for the previous PNI sites you have created.
2. Some of the configuration data may be saved in your local `applicationhost.config` file (if you set up these sites and used IIS Express). *Typically* one of these paths will get you there:

   - `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`
   - `%userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`

   Look for the `<sites>` node, and delete any `<site>` nodes under it which look like your PNI site.

Comment: Yeah I did this, it's still numbering them, I think I'm just going to get over myself and name it something else. It just really bothers me that I know it's still there numbering my sites wrong.